# Questioning my own understanding on a theorem on functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

My understanding of this theorem is as follows.

So after watching episode 9 of 3blue1brown's linear algebra series, the main point from that is that we could treat vectors themselves as linear transformations (e.g when multiplied with another vector). I observed that the inner product operator is a linear functional, as it takes two vectors and maps to a scalar.

So to make a bold guess, the theorem above is saying that for every inner product space, there is a functional that transform a vector in the same way as an inner product with a particular vector in the same space.

Im also guessing that one of the "functional" within the space is just the inner product itself.

Please correct me if my intuition is wrong or Im heading towards the wrong direction. Any extra information would be appreciated, thank you

P.S what does the adjoint operator do ?

Comment: Well, it is clear, is it not?, that every vector $\vec v$ defines a linear functional, let's call it $L_{\vec v}$ by the rule $L_{\vec v}(\vec w)=<\vec w, \vec v>$.  The claim here is that you get $\textit {every}$ linear functional this way and that the vector defined this way is unique.

Comment: So you're saying that firstly, every vector is a linear functional. Secondly, what do you mean by every linear functional ? So like every unique pair of vectors in an inner product can yield all linear functionals ?

Comment: No, I am saying that every vector defines a linear functional, in the way I described.  For your second question...I mean, that if you give me any linear functional on a reasonable vector space (let's say finite dimensional) then it must be of the form $L_{\vec v}$ for some vector $\vec v$.  That's really not trivial,  you need to prove it.

Comment: To stress;  it's not right to say "every vector is a linear functional" because identifying $\vec v$ with $L_{\vec v}$ presupposes a particular inner product.  There are lots of unner products, there's nothing unique about one.  But if you have specified an inner product then the Theorem you quote says that there is a way to identify the space of linear functionals with the space of vectors.

Comment: Your last point is quite interesting. As in to say that the space of a specific inner product, corresponds to a particular space of linear functionals and vice versa ?

Comment: I am saying;  If you specify an inner product on a finite dimensional vector space $V$  then there is a natural way to identify $V$ with the space of linear functionals on $V$.  That's the content of the Theorem you quote.

Comment: I assume you are working with finite dimensional vector spaces, yes?  The situation gets quite complicated for general vector spaces.

Comment: yes, I'm using Axler, so far only finite dimensional spaces have been considered